# Reddit API (PRAW) - Is it possible to access the followers of a Redditor or get number of followers a Redditor has?

Tags: reddit, praw

Without being a friend of the Redditor, is it possible to obtain any information on the followers they have? Whether that be the followers themselves or the number followers they have.

Comment: I looked through latest PRAW and Reddit API docs but haven't found what you are looking for. I'd say not officially possible. Let's see if Cunningham's law applies here.

Comment: I agree — I wasn't able to find this information using the technique from [Determine Available Attributes of an Object](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object) on a `Redditor`.